# mail relay from web application / tool

Tags: email, web-applications, google-apps

What is the best way to send mail notification from web application?

I have domain that uses google apps for the mail service.

I want my application to be able to send mail to the users and I tried to use SmtpClient of asp.net to perform the job.

Google block my sender user since i'm sending more than 50 mails.

What is the best way to perform this task? should i install my own mail server? does google offer such service?

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to Google Apps for Business and you'll have a higher per day quota. :)

Also, there's a class of applications known as email delivery services.  They take care of emailing for you, so you don't have to run a mail server as part of your development.  I recommend SendGrid.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to send mail notification from web application?

There are four options, only one of which is very good (in my opinion) ;)

1. **depricated option** Set SPF records on your webservers IP address and send mails directly from there. Thats very high maintenance as most Email providers have whitelists with IPs from which they accept emails. This has been a thing many years ago, but isn't anymore.
2. **very high volume option** Use an API like [mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/) to send mails via API calls. Thats a good solution unless the API is down, then your webapp needs to be able to do error handling for that. Also its rather pricey while you can get a normal SMTP address for free. If you have a very high volume of mails, maybe go with something like mailchimp. In any case, if you send out newsletters or so, you need a provider thats build for that, or you need to adjust the limits in the providers settings. Otherwise you might get rate limited.
3. **webapp has SMTP credentials option** If you import a library in your webapp to talk SMTP, and you give this library your SMTP credentials make sure it can do error handling and will not just log something to error and then drop the mail. Thats a good way to "loose emails".
4. **imho best solution: local mailrelay** Use a local mailrelay using Postfix or OpenSMTPD, where you setup SMTP authentication credentials of the SMTP account(s) that you want your webapp to send mails with. From your webapps perspective all you have to do is set the correct sender (MAIL FROM) address and then give the mail to 127.0.0.1:25. The mailrelay will do the rest. If you get rate limited the mailrelay will keep the mails in its queue and try again periodically.

Personally I think using a Mailrelay is the the best approach. You can do this with [Postfix](https://www.postfix.org/), but the config is rather annoying for such a small task. Postfix is more suited to larger Mail environments (incoming and outgoing for many mail users) and just to complex to setup and debug for a simple mailrelay. I have recently switched to [OpenSMTPD](https://www.opensmtpd.org/) and am very happy with it.

There are many tutorials on how to setup a SMTP mailrelay for webservers with [this one](https://www.blunix.com/blog/secure-smtp-email-relay-on-debian-and-ubuntu-with-opensmtpd-instead-of-postfix.html) being the most detailed and easy to follow one I have found so far.

> What is the best way to perform this task? should i install my own mail server?

Running your own mailserver is possible with solutions like [mail in a box](https://mailinabox.email/) or similar FOSS tools. I personally wouldn't recommend that though, as often times large mail providers have whitelists (I'm looking at you microsoft) that will just block your mails, and then you have to maintain that mailserver and do things to get your IP unblocked. Many smaller email providers also fell for dubious blocklist schemes, where you have to pay the blocklist provider to unblock your IP (NEVER do that - a good blocklist like [spamhouse](https://www.spamhaus.org/) will unblock you automatically after a period of time).